# Menu with buttons selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, selection

I would like to ask you for some help.
I want to write a code with javascript which will make a selection.
Something like this:
There is 10 buttons defined. Every one has a value at start.
When I click on one of them, the button texts should changed to the submenu names.
Then click on a submenu, and the click action should add the button text to a variable.
Then this process few more times.
All of the variables should be shown after that as simple text.

How would you do this?
I don't want anybody to write a code for me, just want to know the way to do this. Is it possible with JavaScript/jQuery?

Maybe my description a bit confusing... sorry about that.

Regards,
Imre

Comment: It is doable using jQuery

Comment: If you want onl;y to know whether Is it possible with JavaScript/jQuery. Then yes it is possible.

Comment: What is the right way to change the button's text and ID? To be able to refer the button by its new ID.